# How to step into a method call when in debug mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def login
    debugger
    LOGIN::authenticate(params)
end
```

When it hits the line with debugger, I type 'n' and it goes to some other file, and I can't seem to be able to get into the call to `LOGIN::authenticate`

Is 'n' not the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `step` or `s` for shorthand. [Here is a great cheat-sheet on ruby-debug](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rdebug/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `step` to step into the `LOGIN::authenticate` method.

`n[ext]` just step over to the next line.

Try `help` to have the list of debugger commands, and `help command-name` to have some help for a given command.